# how to read mails from Exchange using mapi

Tags: c#, mapi

I'm beginner to C#. Now I'm trying to develop a mail reading application that uses the MS Exchange native protocol (mapi) in C#.

I have tried using `EAgetmail.dll` which is available over the internet. It was working fine but now I'm trying without using third party dll.

Whether any codings are available for without using the Dll or any source code is available for your recommended dll. If you feel any possibilities to resolve my issue please share the codings or say me the website to refer. Your support will be great helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read Exchange mailbox through the EWS Interface (Exchange Web services) - it will work for exchange 2007 and greater.
Please have a look at the CodeProject Article: [Exchange Web Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399015/Exchange-Web-Services)

Another option for older Exchange servers would be to use the Collaboration Data Objects Library (CDO.DLL).

[Using Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) to check for new Exchange email](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6133/Using-Collaboration-Data-Objects-CDO-to-check-for)

[Accessing the inbox through MAPI using C# .NET](http://bytes.com/topic/net/insights/795371-accessing-inbox-through-mapi-using-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the native .net System.Net.Mail to do this

check out this example on the msdn site.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer but i have asked for the reading mails using native protocol