# Send Email using Exchange Server

Tags: email, c#-4.0, exchange-server

I have an exchange account. I need to send an email with it. I tried sending with SmtpClient and it fails. I have few questions after googling

1. What are the things needed to send email with an exchange account?
2. What's difference between WebDav and MAPI? Which should be used?

Any Ideas?

Here is my code. I think this can't be done with SMTP.

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com", "Sender");
mailMessage.To.Add("receiver@domain.com");
mailMessage.Subject = "Test Exchange Email";
mailMessage.Body = "Sameple test message";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Exchange Server Url");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Port = 465;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: Is SMTP enabled on your Exchange server? Because if it's not ... no you can't send email via SMTP. If it is ... yes you can.

Comment: SMTP is not enabled, If it is enabled, Is it good to use SMTP with Exchange Server?

Comment: If by "googd" you mean "extremely easy way to send emails via Exchange" then yes.

Comment: I don't want to use SMTP. How to proceed with Exchange Server using WebDav or MAPI ?

Comment: Consider using EWS. Regardless, some info on EWS and MAPI is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263698/242520

Comment: Thanks! Let me check!

Comment: @ta.speot.is Is it necessary to have Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 installed for sending mail through EWS?

Comment: @SSS I seriously doubt that SMTP is disabled, otherwise you'd be unable to send or receive *any* emails. SMTP is *the* standard for email servers. IMAP or POP3 are *mailbox* access standards. MAPI is a *dekstop only API*. What error are you getting? Is there an exception? How do you know that it fails? BTW WebDav and MAPI are completely unrelated